# How to connect with HIVE via R with Kerberos keytab?

Tags: r, hadoop, hive, kerberos, keytab

I am trying to connect to a Hive server via R remotely, and to perform the authentication i use a Kerberos keytab file.

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod",
>   cl,  :    java.io.IOException: Login failure for
>   antonio.silva@HADOOPREALM.LOCAL from keytab
>   C:/Users/antonio.silva/Desktop/jars/antonio.silva.keytab:
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: null (68)

But when i try to login the user via keytab, the error appears.

```
#loading libraries

library("RJDBC")

hadoop.class.path <- list.files(path = c("C:/Users/antonio.silva/Desktop/jars/hadoop/"), pattern = "jar", full.names = T)
hive.class.path <- list.files(path = c("C:/Users/antonio.silva/Desktop/jars/hive/"), pattern = "jar", full.names = T)
class.path = c(hadoop.class.path,hive.class.path)
.jinit(classpath=class.path)
conf = .jnew("org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration")
conf$set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos")
ugi = J("org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation")
ugi$setConfiguration(conf)
path = "C:/Users/antonio.silva/Desktop/jars/antonio.silva.keytab"
ugi$loginUserFromKeytab('antonio.silva@HADOOPREALM.LOCAL', path)
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Search for the Java properties to enable verbose traces for Kerberos config & negotiation  2. Get some actionable error messages from there  3. Spend months acquiring experience in Kerberos troubleshooting  : -/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it turns out, I needed the MIT Kerberos conf file (krb5.conf) to be placed in the java directory ""~\Java\jre1.8.0_192\lib\security".

After pasting the file in the directory, I was able to perform the connection successfully and connected to the Hive server, with the use of the following code in addition of the code published earlier:

```
drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://hivename:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@HADOOPREALM.LOCAL")
```

This credentials validations are valid when it is needed to perform a connection via R to the HDFS, where I placed an answer about the connection and the configurations needed to do in order to Read and Write the files in the HDFS server with R.

HDFS configuration: [How to acess to HDFS via R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648755/how-to-acess-to-hdfs-via-r)