# How to acess to HDFS via R?

Tags: r, hadoop, hdfs

So, I am trying to connect to a HDFS server via R remotely on a Windows machine.

I use RStudio with the "rhdfs" package, however, and since I had to create the `HADOOP_CMD` environment variable, I downloaded the Hadoop to my machine in order to give the environment variables, and change the core-site.xml.

Previously I tried, sucessfully a connection the Kerberized Hive server with a Keytab.

Here is my code:

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_STREAMING = 
"C:/Users/antonio.silva/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD = 
"C:/Users/antonio.silva/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME = 
"C:/Users/antonio.silva/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.3")
Sys.getenv("HADOOP_STREAMING")
Sys.getenv("HADOOP_CMD")
Sys.getenv("HADOOP_HOME")

#loading libraries
library(rJava)
library(rmr2)
library(rhdfs)

#init of the classpath 
hadoop.class.path <- list.files(path = c("C:/Users/antonio.silva/Desktop/jars/hadoop/"), 
pattern = "jar", full.names = T)
.jinit(classpath=hadoop.class.path)

hdfs.init()
```

After perform the hdfs.init() method and perform the hdfs.defaluts(), the fs variable and the working directore are the same directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What fs variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out a solution to this.

If the server has the Kerberos authentication method, a keytab authentication can be useful to access the server. 
See [How to connect with HIVE via R with Kerberos keytab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618077/how-to-connect-with-hive-via-r-with-kerberos-keytab/53721395#53721395).

After that, it is need to Download to your machine, in this case, a Windows machine, the same version of Hadoop present in the cluster and place the Hadoop a Windows directory.

Then, to configure the Hadoop you need to follow these steps until the point "Hadoop Configuration".
[Step by step Hadoop 2.8.0 installation on Window 10](https://github.com/MuhammadBilalYar/Hadoop-On-Window/wiki/Step-by-step-Hadoop-2.8.0-installation-on-Window-10)

The Hadoop in the cluster contain some configuration files that will be used in your local machine. The files are the core-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml. They contain the information about the cluster, such as the default FS, what type of credentials used in the Cluster, the Hostname and the Port used.

Additional: To use the Hostnames when connecting to Datanodes, you need to add these lines in the hdfs-site.xml file.

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Whether clients should use datanode hostnames when
connecting to datanodes.
</description>
  </property>
```

Finally, in R use the following code to perform the connection:

```
#set The Environment variables in R
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME = "C:/Users/antonio.silva/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/winutils.exe")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD = "C:/Users/antonio.silva/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_STREAMING = "C:/Users/antonio.silva/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar")

library(rhdfs)


hdfs.init()
hdfs.ls("/")
```

And that all needed to perform the connection to an Kerberized Hadoop Cluster.

Comment: What need to be the steps for non-Kerberized cluster? I want to connect to remote Hadoop cluster from local R server. I will download same hadoop binary as the cluster and keep the configs same as that of cluster and thats it? is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart R environment.
If using Rstudio perform Session --> Restart R

Now do load libraries and do

```
 hdfs.init().
```